# Boost-Asio: how to handle stream data from either console and network?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Boost-Asio doc says it can handle both console and network. The tutorial I read are mostly about networking (TCP/IP) examples. Can someone kindly show me how to handle streaming data from console as well? (e.g. piped in from cin). Better yet, is there a way I can switch between these two mode to ease the testing process? (where binary protocol data will be piped into the program)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(input_, input_buffer_, '\n',
      boost::bind(&posix_chat_client::handle_read_input, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

where input is a `posix::stream_descriptor`